# Linux and GeForce 8400 dual monitor

Tags: installation, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-9.10, nvidia-graphics-card, fedora-12

I'm trying to install a linux distribution on my PC.

I have a GeForce 8400 GS with two connected monitors.  I tried with Fedora 12 and Ubuntu 9.10 (both 64 and 32 bit) and the live cd cannot boot properly.

I don't get a visible error on Ubuntu, it simply hangs up during the boot.
With Fedora I get this error:

```
[drm] Modeset on unsupported output type
[drm] Table 0x0000 not found for 1/1 using first
```

I tried to disconnect one of the two monitor and was able to install on my HD and boot from there, but if I try to connect the second monitor again I cannot boot.

Do I need to install something else? (a driver for my video card for example).

Comment: Install the NVidia-Drivers (using the Hardware-Manager in Ubuntu, not the Website-Download) and try again.

Comment: @Bobby Using Hardware-Drivers to install nvidia drivers solved the boot problem. I still cannot use the second monitor but now I know what to look at. If you cange your comment into an aswer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the NVidia-Drivers (using the Hardware-Manager in Ubuntu, not the Website-Download) and try again. I had a similar situation once, and it seemed like the generic vesa driver couldn't handle the monitor + graphiccard combination for some reason.

From there you should be able to use the Nvidia-Settings tool (located in System, Administration) for setting up your two monitors.

Answer (score 0):

do you have another box you can try? are you certain the card works? i've had more than two 8400 GS's dead on arrival. one was a bfg tech the other an nvidia

Comment: I haven't another box. I currently use the same machine in windows vista with two monitors so I suppose the video card isn't broken.